# ie7: background image does not show up at all

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

```
body {
    background: #f6f6f6 url(http://path.to.image/body-bg.gif) repeat-x;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

works in everything but ie7.

what's wrong here?

Comment: Please setup a jsfiddle of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url(/body-bg.gif)` is skipped by ie7 use `url(body-bg.gif)` instead!

Comment: well, its actually an absolute path, including the http:// and everything, I just didn't want to put it up here.

Comment: in case you're wondering, partial paths are relative to the location of the CSS, not the HTML that is using it. So you can safely refer to the image with ../etc/body-bg.gif and use it on any HTML even in subdirectories.

Comment: hmm strange, did you try splitsing them in seperate 'tags' (dont know if tags are the correct name) I mean like background-color:#f6f6f6;background-image:url(http://path.to.image/body-bg.gif);background-repeat:repeat-x; ?

Comment: Tim is close, see http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml 3. Disappearing background images

Comment: I know this is 3 years old, but why did this get marked as the correct answer when your final comment was that it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the line-height is causing the issue, try taking it out. Also, try body { height:1%; }